# How can I resolve this linting error? "Consider adding meta keywords. <html lang="en-US"> (H031)"

Tags: html, django, lint

I'm pretty stumped here. I get that it's telling me I should add meta keywords but which ones ? what am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: <html lang="en"> only use this

Comment: @ManojTolagekar, I've tried that same result

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the same problem.

Please try adding a meta element `name="description"` as follows.

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="keywords" content="foo,bar"/>
        <meta name="description" content="foo"/>
        <!-- etc -->
    </head>
    <!-- etc -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and solved it by adding `<meta name="keywords" ... >` into `<head>`.

e.g.

```
 <head>
     ...
     <meta name="keywords" content="foo,bar" />
     ...
 </head>
```

Comment: I had to all all three (`description`, `charset`, `keywords`). djlint v 1.30.2